# how to set desired location directory when installing

Tags: software-installation

I jusk know apt-get in terminal. and i am bigginer. so i need you help.
When installing, it is easy to select location on Windows. In the time installing, clicking the next, it will show me up. But i don't know how to set it up on Ubuntu. How can i get this? 
If you know to be separated, please let me know. one is there are no one of folders that i wanted(in this case, i should make folder and then installing that folder. 
the other is there is folder i wanted. So i just install to this folder.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. In Linux usually you don't choose where a programs are installed because you don't really install programs but packages and scripts that might depend on each other so it would make no sense if the system allows you to choose where to place them.

Comment: I think you probably mean how to setup different partitions on the hard drive so one is used as / and one as /home ??

Answer (score 2):

In GNU/Linux every file has its own place, we don't install all files in a same folder, when you are using `apt-get` it does the job automatically you don't have to do anything.

Every package you install follows an standard "Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)".
It defines the directory structure and directory contents in Unix-like operating systems [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlftD.jpg)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

You can use `man hier` to see what each path supposes to do, e.g: binary files are located at `/bin` or `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, or configuration files will be placed at `/etc`.

You can also use `dpkg -L pkg-name` to find out where a package files are located at system, e.g:

```
dpkg -L wget
```

There is a case when you download a whole program (mostly pre-compiled) which all of its files are located in a same directory, in that case we place it at `/opt/progam-name`.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is not windows and when you install from a .deb with the package manager of your choice (apt-get, software center, dpkg, etc) the locations of the installed files are defined in the .deb and you can not change any of this.

If you must, you can rebuild the .deb and specify custom locations, but in doing so you would need to understand the linux file system and locations of libs and various documents such as man files.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview

If you specify a non-standard location you would then need to modify your environmental variables to include your custom locations.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Last you could of course build from source, modify the source code and specify custom locations, but you then face the same issues as if you rebuild the .deb, ie using standard locations or modifying environmental variables to include your custom path. See above links.

Without specific details I can not give specific instructions.